# Does OMNET++ 6.0 support runtime configuration?

Tags: simulation, omnet++, inet

I am attempting to create a plug-and-produce (PnP) simulation using OMNET++. The PnP scenario necessitates the online configuration of network parameters such as routes or schedules during the simulation's execution. However, I'm unsure if this is possible in OMNET++ version 6.0 since I couldn't find any specific references in the manual.
Is there any reference or method to implement this online configuration function for OMNET++?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a `@mutable` parameter. Take a look at the [specific chapter](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:mutable) in the manual. In short, you should mark your parameter with `@mutable` and implement the `handleParameterChange()` callback in your C++ code. If you are using INET, all parameters that support this behaviour are properly marked with `@mutable` annotation.

Also a point of interest might be the `ScenarioManager` which can change these parameters during the runtime.